# Cleaning up CSV -- starting a new line

Tags: python, csv

sorry for the stupid question. I am not sure if I am just tired or what, but I am having a hard time trying to figure out the logic of solving this problem.

I have a csv that looks like this:

```
Company,CompanyName,
Website,WebsiteName ,
Website, WebsiteName2,
Email, emailData,
Company,NextCompanyName,
Website,websiteName,
Website, WebsiteName2,
Company,NextCompanyName,
Name,PersonName,
Website,websiteName,
```

as you can see, it is pretty nasty data. What I would like to do is read in the entire CSV, and separate each line by CompanyName and try to organize as much data as possible.  Sometimes the company has a person's name, sometimes it has multiple websites, sometimes an email, and sometimes not.

So my desired output would be:
Company Name, Person's Name, Email Address, Web1, Web2, etc

The good news is that all the data has a separator on each row (Company, Website, Name, etc).  What I am wanting to do is read through the CSV, and when it finds a row that looks like Company, CompanyName that it starts a new row and sorts the data (Name to Name Column, email to emailColumn, etc until it runs into another row that looks like Company, CompanyName.

I dont need help reading / writing to the csv.  I am looking for help on how to properly iterate over the data and sort the data to where it needs to be.

Thanks for any suggestions you can give me

Comment: Are you saying that the data between "Company" and "Company" comprises one set of key - value pairs pertaining to a single record? So for example, in your above case, we have a Company with name "CompanyName", two websites - WebsiteName and WebsiteName2, and one email - emailData?

Comment: Do you know the all of the property names in advance... or which ones will have 1 or multiple items?

Comment: Gratus D. correct the data between "Company" and "Company" comprises one data set.

Comment: Honestly all that matters is Company Name, Person Name, Email, and the rest can be all MISC columns

Answer (score 1):

You can check for a record start condition as you iterate the lines of the file. Record each key/value pair in a `dict` and when you see the start, you know the existing record is complete. You can make the values in your record dict a list and append new values as you find them.

```
from collections import defaultdict
import csv
import re

filename = 'mytest.csv'

# test data
open('mytest.csv', 'w').write("""Company,CompanyName,
Website,WebsiteName ,
Website, WebsiteName2,
Email, emailData,
Company,NextCompanyName,
Website,websiteName,
Website, WebsiteName2,
Company,NextCompanyName,
Name,PersonName,
Website,websiteName,""")

# will hold dict for each company
records = []

with open(filename, newline='') as in_fp:
    record = defaultdict(list)
    for row in csv.reader(in_fp):
        if len(row) >= 2:
            if row[0].strip() == "Company" and "Company" in record:
                # found new company... record old as long as it has data
                records.append(record)
                record = defaultdict(list)
            record[row[0].strip()].append(row[1].strip())

for record in records:
    print('----')
    print(record)
```

Comment: Thanks, that got me on my way.  Appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple condition, and sort everything into lists, or even a single dictionnary (although that is a little more complicated I think, but not much)

```
companyList = []
with open("foo.csv", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        if "Company" in line:
            companyList.append(line.split(',')[1])
```

with a list for each of your rows, then rebuild your csv how you want it to be, and write it.